# how to use javascript in c#

Tags: c#, javascript

How can I use javascript with a C# application.  Also, how can I create an HTML popup window?

actually my need to create a plugin for ie, which uses JSON response to create its elemtts and need a popup for login , which should be an html file

Comment: You mean asp.net web application?

Comment: Depends.  Did you want to call a Web Service?  Please explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call javascript function you can use

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript
```

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx)

For the second part you can use

```
window.open
```

method

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/met_win_open.asp)

Comment: Deprecated from .NET 2.0. Use Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript instead.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp/)?

Script# brings the power and productivity of C# and .NET tools to Ajax development by compiling C# source code into regular JavaScript.